# What is the correct way to set up a store/store views?

Tags: magento2, multistore, store-view

I am new to Magento and am after some rather initial guidance.

Firstly, what is the correct way to set up stores / store views? Should it be as per option one or two below?

Option 1

```
>WEBSITE
>>Australia [AUD]
>>>English

>>United States [USD]
>>>English

>>Europe [EUR]
>>>English
>>>French
>>>Spanish
>>>Greek
```

Option 2

```
>WEBSITE
>>STORE
>>>Australia [AUD]
>>>United States [USD]
>>>Europe [EUR]
```

Answer (score 0):

**To create a store:**

In the Admin panel, click **Stores > Settings > All Stores**.

On the Stores page, click **Create Store**.

**Web Site**—Click the name of the website with which to associate this store.

**Name**—Enter a name to identify the store.

**Code**—Enter a unique code to identify the store.

**Root Category**—Click the name of the root category for this store.
The following figure shows an example.

**To create a store view:**

In the Admin panel, click **Stores > Settings > All Stores.**

On the Stores page, click **Create Store View**.

**Store**—Click the name of the store with which to associate this store view.

**Name**—Enter a name to identify this store view.

**Code**—Enter a unique name to identify this store view.

**Status**—Select Enabled. The following figure shows an example.

Answer (score 0):

## Website Base Currencies (Transactions with different currencies)

If you intend on allowing customers to checkout with different **base currencies**, you will need to setup different **websites** per base currency accepted as payment. This is due to Magento only allowing a base currency down to the website scope.

Option 3

```
> Website (Australia) [AUD]
>> Store Group
>>> Store View (English)

> Website (United States) [USD]
>> Store Group
>>> Store View (English)

> Website (Europe) [EUR]
>> Store Group
>>> Store View (English)
>>> Store View (French)
>>> Store View (Spanish)
>>> Store View (Greek)
```

**Exception:** This blog article by BSS Commerce explains the base currency situation a little more, and also offers a module that claims to allow checkout with different base currencies per store view. I have not used their module/extension and am not endorsing it in any way, just posting the blog article for more knowledge or if you want to go down the path of allowing transactions in different currencies per store view:

[How to Set up Different Currencies for Different Magento 2 Store Views - BSS Commerce](https://bsscommerce.com/blog/how-to-set-up-different-currencies-for-different-magento-2-store-views/)

## One Base Currency, Different Display Currencies

If you are okay with all transactions happening in the same base currency while having different currencies *displayed* to customers in the store groups / store views, I believe you would be good to go with **Option 2**. Option 2 will also let you retain the different store views / languages. Here are some details from a two part Amasty blog post on multi-language sites:

[Create a multi-language store in Magento 2 - Part 1](https://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-create-multilanguage-store/)

[Create a multi-language store in Magento 2 - Part 2](https://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-administration/create-multi-language-store-magento-2-part-2/)

I don't know if I would suggest **Option 2** based on the following factors:

- Each store view representing a country means you can't have different languages per store view / country.
- Currencies per store view are only "Display" currencies, so users will still be checking out with one common base currency

## Additional Information

[Magento Docs - Stores](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/stores-all-stores.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response - this is really helpful.

Comment: Hi Floorz, are you able to check out this post https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/282005/setting-up-multi-website-store-views it's a follow on from this question